# Get size of block device Linux/Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

I have a task to get size of block devices, it must be cross-platform application (Linux/Windows) so I use Qt, can I get file size of block devices usin Qt standard classes such as QFile and QFileInfo? My sketch program doesn't work correct:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QFileInfo>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QFileInfo info("/dev/sda5");
   if(info.isReadable())
       std::cout<<"/dev/sda1 isReadable\n";
   else
       std::cout<<"Cant read /dev/sda5";

   std::cout<<info.size()<<"\n";

   return a.exec();
}
```

It shows "/dev/sda5 isReadable" and size equals zero, can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`statfs`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/statfs) on Linux and [`GetDiskFreeSpaceEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364937.aspx) on Windows. It does not seem that Qt was wrapping that function, but it's rather short piece of code.

Device nodes report size of zero via usual stat call. That's a fact and you can't do much about it. It's not interesting anyway, because it's quite a lot of unix-specific work to find out which device is mounted on some path.

Answer (score -2):

On the Linux side, there are two utilities that will help with enumerating attached storage partitions, depending on your distro:  **blkid** and **vol_id**.  I've used these to identify possible partitions (and their type) for a Samba server setup script.  One could redirect their output to a text file and parse the result in your C code.  HTH.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address a key part of the OP's question - how to perform this in a cross platform app. The tools you suggested are linux only.